# What is causing this Segmentation Fault in C?

Tags: c, pointers, hashmap, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm working on a program for a course of mine, so I'd appreciate it if answers were kept abstract. I am working on a key-value hash table in C that stores a string for a key and an int for the value. I'm getting a segmentation fault on the helper function for the put() method. Below is the problematic code. I've changed it slightly for academic honesty purposes, and I've only included the parts that lead up to the error. I've tried adjusting how I dereference or don't dereference `table[index]->symbol`, but to no avail. I'm thinking that that line that the SEGFAULT is happening on probably isn't the culprit, but I'm struggling to find where it might otherwise appear. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated, be it GDB hints, high-level explanations, etc. I just ask that code snippets be kept vague so that I actually learn, rather than just being told an answer. Thank you!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
 
typedef struct elem_t elem_t;
struct elem_t {
    const char* symbol;
    void* data;
    elem_t* next;
};
 
typedef struct {
    size_t length;
    size_t size;
    elem_t** table;
} table_t;
 
static unsigned int hash(const char *str) {
    const unsigned int p = 16777619;
    unsigned int hash = 2166136261u;
    while (*str) {
        hash = (hash ^ *str) * p;
        str += 1;
    }
    hash += hash << 13;
    hash ^= hash >> 7;
    hash += hash << 3;
    hash ^= hash >> 17;
    hash += hash << 5;
    return hash;
}
 
 
void *createTable(int sizeHint) {
    table_t* table;
    table = malloc(sizeof(table));
    if (table == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    table->length = 0;
    table->size = sizeHint * 2;
 
    table->table = calloc(table->size, sizeof(elem_t*));
    if (table->table == NULL) {
        free(table);
        return NULL;
    }
 
    return table;
}

static const char* putHelper(elem_t** table, size_t size, const char* symbol, void* data, size_t* length) {
    unsigned int hashVal = hash(symbol);
    size_t index = (size_t)(hashVal & (unsigned int)(size - 1));
 
    while (table[index]->symbol != NULL) { // !!! SEGFAULT HERE !!!
        if (strcmp(symbol, table[index]->symbol) == 0) { // collision
            elem_t* cur = table[index];
            while (table[index]->next != NULL) { // separate chaining
                cur = cur->next;
            }
            elem_t* newElem = (elem_t*)malloc(sizeof(elem_t)); // make new element to hang at the end of the chain
            cur->next = newElem;
            newElem->data = data;
            newElem->symbol = symbol;
            newElem->next = NULL;
            return newElem->symbol;
        }
        index++;
        if (index >= size) {
            index = 0;
        }
    }
 
    if (length != NULL) {
        symbol = strdup(symbol);
        if (symbol == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        (*length)++;
    }
    table[index]->symbol = (char*)symbol;
    table[index]->data = data;
    return symbol;
}
 
int put(void *tableHandle, const char *symbol, void *data) {
    table_t* table = (table_t*)tableHandle;
    if (data == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
 
    table->length++;
    const char* result = putHelper(table->table, table->size, symbol, data, &table->length);
    if (result != NULL) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
 
 
int main() {
    table_t* table = createTable(200);
    int result = put(table, "t1", 25);
    if (result == 0) {
        printf("put failed");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: For your problem(s), it's kind of hard to just hint without giving away the code [as the two answers you got show]. But, if you'd like to learn, before applying the fixes, try compiling with `-g -fsanitize=address`. This will add _lots_ of checking for stack and heap array overflows. If you disassemble the resultant code, you'll see all the check code that gets added. So, much too slow for production or normal running, but great for cases like this one.

Comment: Also, your posted code won't compile cleanly. The compiler flagged `int result = put(table, "t1", 25);` You're passing the 3rd arg (an `int`) to a `void *` argument in the function `put`. For testing, you can just do: `(void *) 25` because you pass `data` around but don't actually do anything with it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You allocated an array of null pointers

```
table->table = calloc(table->size, sizeof(elem_t*));
```

and then you are using null pointer tp access memory

```
while (table[index]->symbol != NULL) { // !!! SEGFAULT HERE !!!
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So the program crashes.

And as **@bbbbbbbbb** pointed out you allocated memory only for a pointer

```
table = malloc(sizeof(table));
```

Comment: Oh man, I don't know how I missed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You by the least need to change this:

```
    table_t* table;
    table = malloc(sizeof(table));
```

To this:

```
    table_t* table;
    table = malloc(sizeof(*table));
```

Or to this:

```
    table_t* table;
    table = malloc(sizeof(table_t));
```